# Offscreenpagelimit vs setItemViewCacheSize ViewPager2

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

I'm using ViewPager2,
newest version `'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0-beta04'`

I have 10 pages and each page is Fragment.

If i set `viewpager2.offscreenPageLimit = 1`
I have to scroll to page 5 to make the first page destroy.

What happened???, the first page supposed to be destroyed when I scroll to page 3 right??

Then i try the other way to make it right

```
(viewpager2.getChildAt(0) as RecyclerView).layoutManager?.isItemPrefetchEnabled = false
(viewpager2.getChildAt(0) as RecyclerView).setItemViewCacheSize(1)
```

This way, the first page will be destroyed when i scroll to page 3, it's working now

Can anyone explain to me the differences between these 2 attributes, please?

Comment: This seems like a bug to me. I've created a report for this in IssueTracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/171180138).

Comment: It seems like this issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150297771

Comment: viewpager2.offscreenPageLimit  = 10, its will worked but very slow